# @font-face not working, fonts seems not to be loaded

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm using the following css to port my own font(on my local machine):

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'byekan';
src: url('~/Content/fonts/BYekan.eot');
src: url('~/Content/fonts/BYekan.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('~/Content/fonts/BYekan.woff') format('woff'),
   url('~/Content/fonts/BYekan.ttf')  format('truetype'), 
   url('~/Content/fonts/BYekan.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); 
}
* {
    font-family: 'byekan';
}
```

but it doesn't work, one thing I noticed is that the fonts are not loaded in the resources tab. The elements got their font-family set to byekan but it seems the fonts are not loaded for some reason. any ideas?

**EDIT:** I've tried accessing the path using my browser and it gives the following http error:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
```

Comment: Do you have all font formats available in fonts folder? You can generate all web font formats at http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Yes, the fonts are available in the fonts folder

Comment: As well as use `font-weight: normal;` and `font-style: normal;` by default.

Comment: didn't make any difference, I've used the link you gave me to generate fonts and it doesn't work with the new generated fonts as well

Comment: could you please create a JSFiddle that illustrates your problem?

Comment: @AlanSouza I'm doing this on my local machine, I'm not sure how I can illustrate it on JSFiddle with my fonts.

Comment: If directly accessing the path of the fonts results in a 403 error, it'll do the same thing when the browser tries to load fonts when loading a page.

You should check whether your server is configured properly, it seems like it's denying access either to that folder, or to font files specifically.

Comment: try losing the `~`, it's not used in regular css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is because you are using ~ to select your home directory.

Try to upload the fonts somewhere else and reference to the files either with absolute URL path:

```
url ('http://www.anywebsite.com/Content/fonts/BYekan.eot');
```

or with relative path for example:

```
url ('Content/fonts/BYekan.eot');
```

In your case the issue it's because you cannot reach the directory containing the font files because CSS does not understand the symbol ~ for referencing your home directory.

Comment: Going with your first suggestion as using absolute URL path worked perfectly fine, although the second suggestion didn't work but I assume I have to stick with the absolute path. thanks

Comment: Both work well, you need to make sure the relative path is the right path. This might help you out http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/